# Wordpress change WP_Query parameters conditionally

Tags: php, wordpress, passwords

Is it possible to change the WP_Query parameters and display all the posts when category slug equls to "All". Where is the function to grab posts in a single category located.?

So, for the following URL it would display all the posts in all categories.

```
mysite.com/category/all
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display all post you can create a custom page template using the `wp_query` to filter all post's. Below is an example of a custom `wp_query` using pagination:

```
<?php
$all_post_query = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post_type'=>'post',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'posts_per_page'=> 10,
    'paged' => $paged
  )
);
?>
```

Then you can loop through and get posts

```
<?php while ( $all_post_query->have_posts() ) : $all_post_query->the_post();
    the_title();
    //more code here
?>
```